# PDF Damaged iTextSharp C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Its my first time i use this itextsharp framework.
I try to convert my Ticket items (Datagrid) to a pdf file.

i dont get any exceptions and the pdf file creates but i cant open it (PDF Damaged).

I hope you can help me

```
                string path = "H://SK/testpdf.pdf";
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(PdfDoc, new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
                PdfDoc.Open();

                var columnWidths = new[] { 0.75f, 1f, 1.5f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f };
                
                var table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths)
                {
                    HorizontalAlignment = Convert.ToInt32(Left),
                    WidthPercentage = 100,
                    DefaultCell = { MinimumHeight = 22f }
                };

                var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Tickets"))
                {
                    Colspan = 4,
                    HorizontalAlignment = 1,
                    MinimumHeight = 30f
                };

                table.AddCell(cell);


                //header

                table.AddCell("Ticketnummer");
                table.AddCell("Ersteller");
                table.AddCell("Meldungstext");
                table.AddCell("Erstelldatum");


                //zeilen
                foreach (Ticket t in lbTickets.Items)
                {
                    table.AddCell(t.Tnr.ToString());
                    table.AddCell(t.Ersteller.ToString());
                    table.AddCell(t.Meldungstext.ToString());
                    table.AddCell(t.Datum.ToString());
                }

                PdfDoc.Add(table);
                PdfDoc.Close();


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
```

Comment: *"i dont get any exceptions"* - remove empty `catch` and try again.

Comment: ou facepalm, recklessness thx

Comment: Furthermore, though, you should use `FileMode.Create` instead of `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, otherwise pieces of a probably existing file at the path might remain and make the result a hodgepodge of old and new.